# How to open VS2005 file/project in VS2013

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2013

I`m working on a project which requires the using of older (2005) library.

When I try to add the library to references, an error pops up telling me that(see picture attached)[image: error]

The following is exception details:

```
System.DllNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=-2146233052
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'edk.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Source=DotNetEmotivSDK
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at Emotiv.EdkDll.Unmanged_EE_EmoEngineEventCreate()
       at Emotiv.EdkDll.EE_EmoEngineEventCreate()
       at Emotiv.EmoEngine..ctor()
       at Emotiv.EmoEngine.get_Instance()
       at MindComposer.EmotivSDK.HeadsetConnection.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Vlado Bogdanov\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MindComposer\MindComposer\NeuroProcessing\HeadsetConnection.cs:line 37
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Well, is the file there? Is it readable?

Comment: Yes it is, it`s a dll and i`m adding it as all others, but only this one is not working.

Comment: From you error message it looks like it's a Native Dll, which can't be added as a reference. You can add it to the project as an item (Add existing item) and set the compile action to: content/copy of newer.

Comment: Ok i`ll give it a try.

Comment: Is not working as intended, still can`t run.